# Period of mass in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, mass, centripetal-force

I've been trying for 4 days now to solve my physics lab assignment but now I'm starting to think there must be a mistake in the question.
You know those rotating mass experiments where you have a mass on one end of a string and another mass on the other end of the string and then you spin the string located in a tube and make the mass move in a circle, like the image below:

[image]
([source](https://www.dorthonion.com/drcmcm/PHYSICS/Lessons/images/))

The assignment says:

> Apply Newton's second law of motion on mass 1 and mass 2 to solve for the period of mass 1.

It gives a hint to assume that $m_1 = 4 m_2$. It also "asks" how the centripetal force of m1 is related to the force of gravity on $m_2$.

It's clear to me that the assignment doesn't want me to calculate with actual values because there are no actual values. So first I thought let's look up some formulas on how to calculate the period T and try to derive my own formula for the problem. But nothing in my books or online show me how to get from knowing only the mass to finding out the period. I keep thinking that I need at least one other component such as the force of $m_1$ or the acceleration or the velocity or the radius etc etc. I know the force on $m_2$ is $F = mg$ but how would that help me to find the force on mass1 when I don't know the acceleration?  To me, the question is incorrect because it simply is not possible to solve for the period of mass 1 when you only know $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your masses are sometimes named "M" and "m", and sometimes "mass 1" and "mass 2"; clarifying this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you need at least the radius $r$. As a hint I tell you that the centripetal force acting on mass 1 is:

- $F_1=m_2g=m_1a_1$

due to action reaction. Then you know $F_1$ and with this you can obtain the period.

- $a_1=\frac{m_2}{m_1}g=\omega^2r$

where $r$ is the radius.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the acceleration on mass1 is the same as the one on mass2 when the shorter string to mass1 is spinning and it's in a perfect horizontal position? In my experiment, I have to take a string of 1 meter and 25cm of that 1 meter is the end out of the tube where mass1 is attached. So I guess the assignment wants me to work with this value for r although it's not exactly given in the assignment.

Comment: Finding velocity:                                                                 a = v^2/r, 9.8 = v^2/r, v = root(ar);                                    Finding period:                                                                   v = 2*pi*r/T; T = 2*pi*r/v = 2*pi*r/root(ar)                        The period T can now be calculated when the radius of mass 1 is known: r = 25cm                                                    T = 2*pi*.25m/root(9.8(m/s^2)*.25m) = 1s                            Is that right? But if yes why would it matter if m2 is 4 times greater than m1?

Comment: sorry, I obviously didn't think about your equation long enough ;) Now I get it and according to the other formulas my textbook gives I can now solve for the period T as shown in my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've got it now...

Newton’s second Law of motion on m1: (mass1 is 4 times less than mass2 in my example)

F = 4mg = ma; a = 4g = 39.2m/s^2

Finding velocity:
                                                                  a = v^2/r, 39.2 = v^2/r, v = root(ar);

Finding period:
v = 2*pi*r/T; T = 2*pi*r/v = 2*pi*r/root(ar)

The period T can now be calculated when the radius of mass1 is known: r = 25cm                                                    T = 2*pi*.25m/root(39.2(m/s^2)*.25m) = .5s